# Sending '&' in a string to php from angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm trying to send a string, for example, "the cat & the dog" to php from angular via GET. I have done `encodeURI(note)` and in php

```
$note = $_GET['note'];
$note = mysql_real_escape_string($note);
```

but when it inserts into the database is only puts any chars before the '&'

Comment: Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: This is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic) as you haven't posted a [mcve].

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
encodeURIComponent(note)
```

Use `encodeURIComponent` when you want to encode a URL parameter

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

instead of

```
encodeURI(note)
```

Use `encodeURI` when you want a working URL

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: That's what i was looking for, thanks